# Linksys EA6500 and Android DHCP

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, android, dhcp

Situation: I have a Linksys EA6500 v2 Wireless-N router. About 2 months ago, I had to perform a factory reset because my ISP refused to accept that my router wasn't the issue with my Internet access. Ever since, I've had this strange issue with my non-PC devices not properly registering on the DHCP. My desktop, laptop, and printer all pull an appropriate IP (192.168.1.*) while my Android devices, game consoles, and my brothers' Roku pull a wrong address (192.168.0.*).

The devices register as having connected to the network with a strong connection, but can't do anything (for obvious reasons), but I can figure out why this is happening.

I've tried doing another factory reset, just in case I screwed something up with the manual configuration, but it didn't seem to change the issue.

Here's my configuration:

```
IPv4 Connection Type: Automatic Configuration - DHCP
IPv6 - Automatic: Enabled
IPv6 DUID: 00:02:03:09:05:05:48:F8:B3:A2:4F:9A
IPv6 6rd tunnel: Disabled
IPv6 Prefix: blank
IPv6 Prefix length: blank
IPv6 Border relay: blank
IPv4 mask length: blank
Domain name: blank
MUT: Auto
Size: 0
MAC Address Clone: Disabled
Host name: Linksys16612
IP address: 192.168.1.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DHCP Server: Enabled
Start IP address: 192.168.1.100
Maximum number of users: 100
Client lease time: 1440
Static DNS 1: 0.0.0.0
Static DNS 2: 0.0.0.0
Static DNS 3: 0.0.0.0
WINS: 0.0.0.0
DHCP Reservations: blank
NAT: Enabled
Dynamic Routing (RIP): Disabled
Static Routing: blank
UPnP: Enabled
Allow users to configure: Enabled
Allow users to disabled Internet access: Disabled
SIP: Disabled
Cut Through Forwarding: Enabled
2.4 GHz: Enabled
2.4 Network mode: Mixed
2.4 Security mode: WPA2 Personal
2.4 Channel width: Auto
2.4 Channel: Auto
2.4 Broadcast SSID: Enabled
5 GHz: Enabled
5 Network mode: Mixed
5 Security mode: WPA2 Personal
5 Channel width: 80 MHz
5 Channel: Auto
5 Broadcast SSID: Enabled
MAC Filters: Disabled
Wi-Fi Protected Setup: On
SimpleTap connection: On
IPv4 SPI firewall protection: Enabled
IPv6 SPI firewall protection: Enabled
IPSec Passthrough: Enabled
PPTP Passthrough: Enabled
L2TP Passthrough: Enabled
Filter anonymous Internet requests: Enabled
Filter multicast: Disabled
Filter Internet NAT redirection: Disabled
Filter ident (Port 113): Enabled
DMZ: Off
DDNS: Disabled
Port Forwarding: blank
Port Range Forwarding: blank
Port Range Triggering: blank
```

I don't know what other information could be needed, but I apologize if I missed something important. Does anyone have any ideas as to where my issue is?

Comment: personal and home computer networking are on-topic if you want to be sure you can check that here http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'd meant to delete that bit. I originally posted on the networking engineer Stack, since I couldn't find any other Stack for networking. ^^'

Comment: are you sure you have not another host providing dhcp? which kind of link have each host wired, wireless?.. provide that info

Comment: All connections are wireless, that's why I used the tag "wireless-networking". As for another DHCP, what else would be controlling DHCP on my local network other than the router that everything connects to?

Comment: There are several devices that may act as DHCP server : a NAS, a print server, even one of your computers, mobile phones.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, none of them is involved, but, just in case, I just finished disconnecting everything from the router except my Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tablet, verified the router registered nothing connected except the tablet, and took the tablet off static configuration. No change in the issue. This all started after the router reset, but nothing else in my network changed. All the equipment is the same, and I can't do anything with the cheap modems the ISP provides.